# How to add a Source Selector on Jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I have 3 M3u8s that I want to add to my jwplayer. On the control bar, there is a pop-up, like if there was an HD button or in the settings wheel to select between the HTML. Here is the code that I'm using to do it, but it loads the first video and there's no button on the drop down to switch between sources. Any help or ideas would be great!

```
sources: [{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d',
label: '720P',
},{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700829~acl=/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media*~hmac=3964553279fa3788f77d0910bfdbe66791fa93bab43f88b5d54beacb84b2649c',
label: '520P',
},{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d',
label: '480P'


    }],
```

Full code

```
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/Ge4D2jW2.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="sXW0XA1MksiJ6hYVNHKJFCtOB4qTihu2B0xyTyZoMiA="</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="video"></div><script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('video').setup({

       sources: [{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d',
label: 'aaaaa',
},{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700829~acl=/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media*~hmac=3964553279fa3788f77d0910bfdbe66791fa93bab43f88b5d54beacb84b2649c',
label: 'aaaa',
},{
            file: 'http://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d',
label: 'aaa'


    }],
 'height': '390',
 'width': '640',
'autostart': 'true',
 'title': '',

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the simplest thing would be to create an m3u8 file like this one.

```
 #EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1012313,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=853x480
    https://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2408695,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=924x520
    https://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700829~acl=/streams/27460990_8266920_lsikdkamp7ufvbg66kn_1/media*~hmac=3964553279fa3788f77d0910bfdbe66791fa93bab43f88b5d54beacb84b2649c
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3042937,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720
    https://playback.akamaized.net/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1@2756000p.m3u8?dw=80&ts=1551528000&hdnts=exp=1551700828~acl=/streams/27460990_8266909_lsiedqtjbbq4ylzyzyc_1/media*~hmac=e4421dcb61cba40f56b7b2ae210a761b5c0c8a7d815bf90080afacfe0b39a33d
```

```
    <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/Ge4D2jW2.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="sXW0XA1MksiJ6hYVNHKJFCtOB4qTihu2B0xyTyZoMiA="</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="video"></div><script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('video').setup({
    "file": "https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/clear/tst/master.m3u8",
     'height': '390',
     'width': '640',
    'autostart': 'true',
     'title': '',

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1012313,CODECS="avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=853x480  how did you come up with that part